# Can we mutate the state in Redux-tool-kit in reducer functions which is imported from another file?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to externalize the reducers logic in a separate file.

My reducer function logic in separate file

```
export const dataReceivedReducer = (state, action) => {
  const questions = action.payload.questions;
  console.log("questions", questions);

  questionsAdapter.setAll(state, questions);
  state.status = "ready";
  state.maxPossiblePoints = questionsAdapter
    .getSelectors()
    .selectAll(state)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.points, 0);

  state.numQuestions = questionsAdapter.getSelectors().selectAll(state).length;
};
```

This is my slice file

```
const quizSlice = createSlice({
  name: "quiz",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    start: startReducer,
    tick: tickReducer,
    newAnswer: newAnswerReducer,
    nextQuestion: nextQuestionReducer,
    finish: finishReducer,
    restart: restartReducer,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, dataReceivedReducer)
      .addCase(fetchData.rejected, dataFailedReducer);
  },
});
```

So can we mutate it like this, is it fine to do ?

Comment: Yes, you can change the value on `state` directly. The `state` parameter is a draft state provided by immerjs

Comment: I also think mutation is fine here. Just be careful to not mix mutation with returning a new state. Btw `state.maxPossiblePoints` looks like this value can be calculated by a selector, are you sure it needs to be written in the state? One of the principles is to keep the state atomic and minimal, so if this value can be derived from the state, you can simply use the selector for it (which can be memoized).